# Достать значения вложенного словаря из JSON от EXMO в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Сразу: программы корябать умею, правда G-code в основном... Решил немного улучшить трэйдбота и тут...
При получении значений от биржи сам себе устроил непонятку.
Требуются данные *buy_price, sell_price, last_trade, high, low* на избранные мною пары.
Вот кусочек кода для повторения ошибок:

```
import urllib, http.client ,urllib.request
import json

with urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.exmo.com/v1.1/ticker") as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode('utf-8'))

print(data)#.decode("utf-8"))
new_a ={}
new_a = data['BTC_USD']#'LTC_BTC','ETH_USD'...
for key in data:
    print(key)

print(new_a)# ожидается вложенный словарь - результат:строка
```

В **new_a** оказывается просто строка, вместо ожидаемого словаря(кортежа...)
Ткните где копать или как исправить...

Comment: Что значит кусочек для повторения ошибок? Не очень, когда требуется у себя запускать непонятный код... Почему сложно всю необходимую информацию включить в текст вопроса?

Comment: Немного исправил. Почему-то опубликовался черновик, может и сам протупил.

Comment: я запустил но у меня вывело {'buy_price': '10722.4', 'sell_price': '10722.97', 'last_trade': '10722.61', 'high': '10850', 'low': '10641.01', 'avg': '10750.57495638', 'vol': '335.78323311', 'vol_curr': '3600472.65324352', 'updated': 1601445180}

Comment: А цикл тоже отработал ? У меня в лучшем случае выдавал первые символы (5-12 шт)

Comment: да у меня все сработало правильно

Answer (score 0):

Как обычно всё оказалось просто.

```
    new_a = dict(data['BTC_USD']) #sort_dict(data)
```

сделал принудительное указание на создание словаря.
и теперь даже:

```
    for key in new_a:
    print(key,new_a[key])
```

тоже отрабатывает, надеюсь другому юному питонисту или криптотрейдеру тоже поможет :)